# Is it possible to recover a lost save in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

One of my characters in Borderlands 2 was level 61, had completed the campaign and had lots of good guns and stuff, but then my save got corrupted somehow and I lost everything.

Is it possible to recover a corrupt save? Otherwise, how can I make a character using the Gibbd Save Editor, that is level 61 and has completed the story?

Comment: Please rewrite the question, it is not very clear what you want to do. By "I made a character that was level 61" you mean that you've also constructed it using a tool, or you mean you actually played the game? Or is this irrelevant, and the question is simply "how to construct level 61 character using save editor?"

Comment: It may also be helpful to add which system you are using as this may have an affect on what/how much you can do. Xbox, PS3, or PC?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, I cannot see any effective way to retrieve the data.

If you have a PC with a constant backup on an external hard drive, you may have a glimmer of hope. You would have to access the backup, wherever it is, and locate the `C:/Programs/Borderlands2` folder and access the saves from there.

I'm unsure if you can do anything if it is on a console,